# why use sparks on engines?

Tags: pressure

When the piston compresses the fuel air mixture, it heats up due to high pressure until in some point it combusts the mixture with the spark plug. What if engines dont have spark plugs, the piston will keep compressing the mixture until it gets very hot to combust itself, as I think it will do, will that really happen? If it does what will be the difference between those methods and which is better?? Edit:: I am talking about compreesing the fuel air mixture together not compressing air and injecting fuel like in diesel engines..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_engine

Comment: I know diesel engines but this is still not what I am talking about. Diesels compress air first then injects fuel. Why not compress both together??

Comment: Have you thought carefully about when the fuel-air mix would ignite in a high compression engine that includes the fuel in at the beginning. Would it be reliably at the right time? How big would the variation be? How would that affect the performance of the engine? But at the core, this is strictly an engineering question rather than physics one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the piston compresses the fuel air mixture, it heats up due to high pressure until in some point it combusts the mixture with the spark plug. What if engines dont have spark plugs, the piston will keep compressing the mixture until it gets very hot to combust itself, as I think it will do, will that really happen?

If a gasoline fueled car could operate without spark plugs, the manufacturers would not include them, as it adds complication (and cost) to the engine, but the compression ratio of a gasoline powered car is not high enough to create the very rapid fuel burn needed to push the pistons down fast enough in the engine cylinders to create a reciprocating effect.

The compression ratio in a gasoline or petrol-powered engine will usually not be much higher than 10:1 due to potential engine knocking  and not lower than 6:1.

In a diesel fuelled car, the compression ratio is high, but it is combined with the heat of the compressed air to  light the fuel.  The diesel engine has the highest thermal efficiency of any internal or external combustion engine because of it's high compression ratio and inherent lean burn process which enables heat dissipation by the excess air. The compression ratio of these engines  will often be in excess of  14:1 and ratios over 22:1 are common.

EDIT Please see the comments by David White on this page, before accepting any answer I have provided here or in my comments to the OP. END EDIT

Comment: So i guess what u mean is if we let it combust by compression only we need a high compression ratio so that the fuel burns but that cant be acheived due to engine knocking?? Tell me if what I understand is right please and thank you so much

Comment: In a gasoline engine yes I agree with what you say, but as you probably know, in the past lead was added to gasoline to reduce knocking. My point here is that with lower compression you still might get combustion but you would need a special,probably toxic fuel. If you are a car maker,you don't spend a cent more than you need to, if you are making millions of cars, so costs play a huge part in this. David's answer gives better details than mine on the knocking part.

Comment: Tysm :) I understand now!

Comment: @AcidJazz, it turns out that I worked for Shell Oil in Deer Park, TX, for a number of years.  I have a total of 6 years experience blending gasoline, and working around such equipment as knock engines, which measure the octane rating of gasoline.  If anyone has a particularly pointed question in this area, I'll try to answer it.

Comment: Regarding gasoline components, tetra-ethyl lead was used because it was cheap and it gave a big octane boost to gasoline.  In the current time frame, a chemical component known as MTBE is used for octane enhancement.  MTBE is somewhat less "toxic" than tetra-ethyl lead, but you still can't expect to use compression ignition for a gasoline-air mixture with MTBE in the gasoline, based on my original comments.

Comment: @DavidWhite re: _If anyone has a particularly pointed question in this area, I'll try to answer it._ I myself would never use this phrase, as it is based on a logical fallacy, an appeal to authority. **Every** user has an **equal** opportunity to answer, if they are wrong, someone will correct them. Users with far more knowledge than I have have never made this remark to me or others, when giving their own answers, as it goes against the ethos of the site. Correct answers are upvoted. I hope you see my point about one person suggesting that answers in any particular area be left to them.

Comment: This is not an appeal to authority.  I merely offered to answer very specific questions based on a lot of experience in this area.  And note: I don't claim to be able to answer each and every question in this area, but in that case, I may be able to suggest further reading that could.

Comment: @DavidWhite and you did give a much better answer than I did, I can't argue that point, regards.

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to use compression ignition in gasoline engines.  If you attempt to compress air and gasoline vapors together to the point where they ignite, the ignition point will not be "controllable".  Ideally, the ignition should occur 10-15 degrees before "top dead center", meaning that the ignition starts when the crank shaft is "under rotated" 10-15 degrees before the piston gets to the top of the cylinder.  This ignition point gives you maximum power, but it is very important that it occur at the correct point.  That is why spark plugs are used - the spark can be very precisely timed such that ignition is started at the correct time.

In case you're wondering, there are occasions where the air and gasoline vapor do actually ignite due to compression in the cylinder, rather than spark timing.  When this happens, the ignition happens too early, and produces knock, which is very bad for mechanical parts.  Such pre-ignition is supposedly caused by hot spots in the cylinder that are due to small amounts of carbon buildup.  This can usually be prevented by using a higher octane gasoline, as higher octane gasoline is more difficult to ignite via compression.

Comment: You may mention that today, the angle is adjusted to the RPM of the engine. High RPM -> early ignition.

Comment: It may be worth noting that diesel engines control the timing of ignition by leaving the cylinder empty of fuel until ignition is supposed to occur, and then pumping fuel into the cylinder under pressure.  For this process to be most effective, most of the combustion shouldn't occur until after the last of the fuel has been added.  Injecting fuel under pressure is more difficult and expensive than feeding it into the air intake, and if one were to use gasoline in a diesel-style engine it would be difficult to feed all the fuel in before rapidly-burning fuel created a major pressure spike.

Answer (score 0):

One is an Otto cycle (with spark plugs, spark ignition), the other one a Diesel cycle (compression ignition). The one producing less green house gas emissions and particles for the same vehicle is probably better.

Comment: I am talking about compressing both together not air only??

Comment: Whatever makes you happy.